# jQuery regexp selector for choose

Tags: jquery, regex, selector

I try using some like this: `$('input[class=^(copy-photo|copy-attachment)]:last')` but doesn't work. Any idea, how to select by simple regexp input with class `copy-photo` or `copy-attachment`?

Comment: You don't really need regexp to select those two specific classes.

$('input.copy-photo,input.copy-attachment')
That will suffice as well

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't have to base selection on the position of a class item in the class attribute string.  jQuery has no native regex selector, so you're just going to have to do it the hard way.

```
$('input[class^=copy-photo],input^=[copy-attachment]').last()
```

Comment: Yeah, some like this, but in one selector, any idea?

Comment: @kicaj you can create a custom selector if you want; something like http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/custom-jquery-selectors.html

Answer (score 0):

almost, you would have to switch =^  to ^=